Sparrow with Keystone Pro and Bitcoin Core
I originally set up Sparrow with a Keystone 3 Pro, and have been using public endpoints. Recently, I set up a Bitcoin Core node in my house. I can successfully connect Sparrow to the node, but all transaction history for my Keystone wallet is missing. Any ideas?


Any ideas?

Ideas yes, but based more on guesswork than on actual experience with Sparrow.
Bitcoin core normally does not maintain an index of all transactions for performance and storage reasons.
It would maintain an index for transactions involving addresses for which it knows the keys, including watch-only/non-spendable addresses for which it already knows only the public key. When you add keys/addresses generated externally I believe you have to tell Bitcoin core to rebuild its transaction indexes by scanning its blockchain records from the genesis block onwards. This is obviously more involved if you have pruning enabled.
Perhaps some essential step was omitted when preparing the connection from Sparrow to Bitcoin core. Consequently none of the transactions of interest to Sparrow are in Bitcoin Core's index.

Yes, I had to go back and index the wallet in bitcoin core. This involved updating my bitcoin.conf file to add server=1 and txindex=1 and also make sure I had wallet= specificed.
Then I had to ultimately perform the bitcoin-cli importdescriptors command. This involved specifying the descriptors in a JSON file. Hope this helps anyone else who gets stuck on it.
